# IE9 browser crashes if we close the window before it finishes loading

Tags: internet-explorer-9, onbeforeunload, frameset

I have a situation here, when I am closing the IE9 browser window before it finishes loading, then the  browser is getting closed and reopen. This results in my web application to crash.
  After some research in websites I came to know that this behaviour is due to the 'Hang Resistance' feature introduced in IE9. As a work around if I display an info message or the like to the user when he clicks on the window close button, then the crashing can be avoided. In my html file I use the below code to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var doneLoading = false;
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
    if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 9") != -1 && !doneLoading)
    return "Closing this window before the page is fully loaded might cause the browser to crash. ";
}
</script>
```

The 'doneLoading ' is a variable to indicate if the window completed the loading of contents.

In my application I am using this logic in a master page which has the  tags and  inside it. The 'doneloading' variable is set to true on 'onload' event of frameset.
Now my problem is, the above Java script code is not getting executed always and I am not getting the IE warning message of browser crash always. 
Please provide some input on why this message is not shown always.